# Issue with jsonify while converting from Python 2.7 to 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have a simple api in Flask that runs fine with Python 2.7.  A view returns a json response by calling `jsonify` on the `transform_data` dictionary.

```
return jsonify(transform_data)
```

Now I'm moving to python 3.4, but I get the following error.

```
raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")

TypeError: ItemsView(OrderedDict([('Car', 1217.62), ('Transfer', 551.86), 'Service Fees', 1313.6), ('MISC Costing', 82.09), ('Air', 35858.23), ('Hotel', 6179.34)])) is not JSON serializable
```

Why am I getting this error?  What do I need to change to make this work on Python 3.4?

Comment: ItemsView? Sounds like subclass of HttpResponse. What type has `transform_data`?

Comment: Can you print `type(transform_data)`? ItemsView is your class definitely. And without your code we can't say why it is passed in the case of python3.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewhere when you create `transform_data`, you set a value to be the items of a dict.  However, `.items()` now returns an `ItemsView` iterator over the dict, rather than a list of tuples.  Find where you've called `.items()` and convert the result to a list: `list(my_dict.items())`.